# Django model how to do many to one mapping?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to map multiple field to same field in vendor and menu class. If I map using foreign key like below it works. But this is not what I want.

```
class OrderItem_Mon(models.Model):

    vendor_name = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    menu_name = models.ForeignKey(Menu, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
    note = models.CharField('note', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

I need to map multiple field to same field of specific table like this.

```
class OrderItem_Mon(models.Model):

    vendor_name_1 = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, db_column='vendor_name', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    menu_name_1 = models.ForeignKey(Menu, db_column='menu_name',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    vendor_name_2 = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, db_column='vendor_name',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    menu_name_2 = models.ForeignKey(Menu, db_column='menu_name', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
    note = models.CharField('note', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

However, it does not work. How do I make this work? Basically, I need to make new form that have dropbox that gets value from vendor and menu model to each field. Help

Answer (score 0):

You need to add related_name attribute for foreign key model fields and give different names.

The error is due to the same model used as a Foreign key for multiple fields. So.it makes an issue during migration. Just setting the different .related_name wont make any issue.